# Reading Messages on Poloniex Trollbox with Python autbahn or other socket module?

Tags: python, sockets, wamp, autobahn, poloniex

Poloniex doesn't return every message to my socket. I read the messages with the following code and sometimes I get continuous message numbers, but sometimes there are like 10 messages missing:

```
from autobahn.asyncio.wamp import ApplicationSession
from autobahn.asyncio.wamp import ApplicationRunner
from asyncio import coroutine

class PoloniexComponent(ApplicationSession):
    def onConnect(self):
        self.join(self.config.realm)

    @coroutine
    def onJoin(self, details):
        def onTrollbox(*args):

            print("type: ", args[0])
            print("message_number: ", args[1])
            print("user_name: ", args[2])
            print("message: ", args[3])
            print("reputation: ", args[4])

        try:
            yield from self.subscribe(onTrollbox, 'trollbox')
        except Exception as e:
            print("Could not subscribe to topic:", e)

runner = ApplicationRunner("wss://api.poloniex.com", "realm1")
runner.run(PoloniexComponent)
```

Does anybody know a better solution? I tried this one, but it doesn't work at all:

```
from websocket import create_connection
ws = create_connection("wss://api.poloniex.com")
ws.send("trollbox")
result = ws.recv()
print "Received '%s'" % result
ws.close()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution:

These missing messages might happen sometimes with the `WAMP API`. It is due to inherent scalability problems with the routing software, and Poloniex is working on a `pure WebSockets API` (currently used by the web interface, but lacking documentation) to replace it. The url for the new websocket server is `wss://api2.poloniex.com:443` and to connect to trollbox messages you would need to send the message: `'{"command" : "subscribe", "channel" : 1001}'`.

Here is an example code, it is much easier to work with:

```
from websocket import create_connection
import json

ws = create_connection("wss://api2.poloniex.com:443")
ws.send('{"command" : "subscribe", "channel" : 1001}')

while True:
    result = ws.recv()
    json_result = json.loads(result)
    if len(json_result) >= 3:
        print(json_result)

ws.close()
```

Comment: you can look at the website source [here](https://poloniex.com/js/plx_exchage.js?v=060617) and look at line 2294 and see that the trollbox subscription is commented.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this code here i made: [Here](https://github.com/andrazpovse/cryptoinfo/blob/master/chatScraper.py). It uses Beautiful soup and dryscape. It gets it by getting on Poloniex website and waiting for some time, then gathers data from website, in our case the Trollbox. I also tried with autobahn, and this is what i got, but it looks exactly like your code, so there would probably be no improvement.

```
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks
from autobahn.twisted.wamp import ApplicationSession,ApplicationRunner

#prints recieved message
def tamperMessage(message):
       print message



class MyComponent(ApplicationSession):

@inlineCallbacks
def onJoin(self, details):
    print("session joined")
    #gets message and calls tamperMessage function
    def gotMessage(type, messageNumber, username, message, reputation):
        tamperMessage(message)

    # 1. subscribe to a topic so we receive events
    try:
        yield self.subscribe(gotMessage,u'trollbox')
   except Exception as e:
       print("could not subscribe to topic:")

runner = ApplicationRunner(url=u"wss://api.poloniex.com", realm=u"realm1")
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I can't get dryscrape to work, but I have found a new and better solution. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

so the trollbox is not functioning right now at the wamp web socket, the reason you are getting a disconnections is due to inactivity.

if you want to check it you can look at the website source [here](https://poloniex.com/js/plx_exchage.js?v=060617) and look at line 2440 and see that the trollbox subscription is commented.

Answer (score 0):

Poloniex trollbox is over now !
You can have access to history [here](http://www.polonibox.com/)