# Websocket with Autobahn stop responding after some hours

Tags: javascript, websocket, autobahn, poloniex

I have a weird problem with Autobahn|JS and the push API on Poloniex.com.
I connect to their API to fetch all messages in their chat and after 1-2 hours, the websocket close without errors, nothing to help me to debug.

I have tested the behavior in 3 langages *(PHP, NodeJS and JS)* and 2 have problems (PHP and NodeJS), my JavaScript test run since 1 day without problems.

The code is very simple:

```
var connection = new autobahn.Connection({url: 'wss://api.poloniex.com', realm: 'realm1'});

connection.onopen = function (session) {
   function onevent(args) {
      console.log("Message:", args[3]);
   }
   session.subscribe('trollbox', onevent);
};

connection.open();
```

I have tested with **Supervisor** for NodeJS and same problem, after 1-2 hours, no response, no error, just not receive message anymore.

I'm new to websocket so I imagine I can test more but the fact that all works in Javascript confused me.

Comment: I have precisely the same issue using autobahn except its in python, with the poloniex api, on market topic . So I guess its traversal to all of their ws. But the thing is that the reconnection is an issue, couldn't figure out how to reconnect yet.

Comment: I would have liked to test with Python tonight but you confirm me that you have the same problem. Very weird. I think that the solution will be to kill manually the socket and launch it again but I don't like that way. If you find a solution, please share, I will do the same.

Comment: don't use this protocol the data arrive with huge delay(~10 hours),look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42436264/reading-messages-on-poloniex-trollbox-with-python-autbahn-or-other-socket-module/) for more data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find a solution so I have implemented my proper "ping". I unsubscribe and subscribe every X minutes (my test run since 1 day with 5 minutes interval). No more deconnection and no missed message from the trollbox.

```
AUTOBAHN_DEBUG = true;

var autobahn = require('autobahn');

(function trollbox() {

  console.log("\n------------- OPEN CONNECTION ---------------\n");
  var connection = new autobahn.Connection({
    url: 'wss://api.poloniex.com',
    realm: 'realm1',
    max_retries: -1
  });

  connection.onopen = function (session) {
    function onevent (args) {

      // Do somethings...
      console.log(args[3]);
    }
    session.subscribe('trollbox', onevent);

    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log("\n------------- CLOSING CONNECTION ---------------\n");
      connection.close();
    }, 300000);

  };

  connection.open();

  setTimeout(trollbox, 300200);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

so the trollbox is not functioning right now, the reason you are getting a disconnections is due to inactivity.

if you want to check it you can look at the website source here [here](https://poloniex.com/js/plx_exchage.js?v=060617)
and look at line 2440 and see that the trollbox subscription is commented.